# overlaying a Label on a Open GL ES View

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios5, opengl-es-1.1

Im trying to overlay a Label (and in the future a UI Image) over my Open GL ES View but nothing is being seen, any idea why? User Interaction and Multi Touch are checked off. Im pretty sure it has something to do with this applicationDidFinishLaunching call but not sure what it could be:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
 {
CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

GLViewController *theController = [[GLViewController alloc] init];
self.controller = theController;
[theController release];

GLView *glView = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[window addSubview:glView];

glView.controller = controller;
glView.animationInterval = 1.0 / kRenderingFrequency;
[glView startAnimation];
[glView release];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to addSubview: puts the GLView instance in front of any other views in the hierarchy. Use one of the insertSubview: methods instead or send your GLView to the back after adding it to the window.